# Plotly: How to adjust the position of sliders and updatemenus to make room for x-axis tickmarks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am using an animation frame in my in my plotly express graph but it overlaps with my x-axis. What can I do ?

This is my code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
fig = px.scatter(data, x = "model", y = "price", color="competitor", hover_data=['Discount'], animation_frame="date")
```

And this is my problem : How can I lower the animation frame bar ? Or maybe put it on top of the graph? Or move the x axis on top of the graph instead of the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily adjust the margins of the plot itself, along with placement of the slider and corresponding updatebuttons by adjusting the padding in:

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=200),paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']=dict(r= 10, t= 150)
fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']=dict(r= 10, t= 150,)
```

The snippet above will turn this:

[image]

... into this:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=200),paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']=dict(r= 10, t= 150)
fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']=dict(r= 10, t= 150,)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how I can reduce the speed of the slider ? When I play it it goes very fast

Comment: @lolaa Happy to help! Not sure about the speed though. But if you write it up as a question in itself I'll take a look at it!